# JavaScript regular expression mobile phone number

Tags: javascript, expression

> 1. XXX-XXX-XXXX
> 2. XXXXXXXXXX
>
> I want to use a regular expression of the format. I tried as shown
>   below, and an error occurs. How do I fix it?

---

1. sample
   var regExp = / ^ 01 ([0 | 1 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9]?) - ([0-9] {3}) - ([0-9] {4}) $ /??;
2. sample
   var regExp = / ^ 01 ([0 | 1 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9]?) ([0-9] {3}) ([0-9] {4}) $ /??;

Comment: Are there spaces in the telephone numbers you're trying to match? No. So first remove every space in your regular expressions.

Comment: seriously? This question must have been asked over 10000 times already on the interwebs.

Answer (score 0):

sample 1

```
var regExp = /^01([016789]?)-([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{4})$/;
```

sample 2

```
var regExp = /^01([016789]?)[0-9]{3}[0-9]{4}$/;
```

just make sure you don't have spaces and remove | from [0|1|6|7|8|9]