# JavaScript regular expression mobile phone number format

Tags: javascript, expression

```
1.XXX-XXX-XXXX

2.XXXXXXXXXX
```

I would like to know the regular expression of the format.
Modifying the existing sources will yield results.

---

```
var regExp = /^01([016789]?)-([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{4})$/;

var regExp = /^01([016789]?)[0-9]{3}[0-9]{4}$/;
```

---

A statement to check the condition.
I wonder if the contact form is also correct.
var test is a text field that receives input.

```
if(!regExp.text) {
        alert(""phone number format is not valid.");
        document.getElementById('phone').focus();
        return ;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript regular expression mobile phone number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40160958/javascript-regular-expression-mobile-phone-number)

Comment: You have already asked this question & it has been marked as a duplicate - why are you asking again?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve, but maybe this example helps:

https://jsfiddle.net/xu9fcbxt/

Notice: jQuery required

**Code:**

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var regExp = /^01[5-7][1-9]-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}/;         

  $('#phone').focusout(function(){
    var text = $('#phone').val();   
    if(!regExp.test(text)){
        alert('not a valid phone number');
    }
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input id="phone" type="text" />
```

This would check if the number has a format like 0151-123-4567